# Combining low-discrepancy sets to produce a low-discrepancy set

Tags: sequences-and-series, reference-request, random, golden-ratio

First of all, I apologize if this is not the right place for this question, I wasn't sure whether it would be more appropriate to post it on stackoverflow or here. I should mention that I am not really knowledgeable when it comes to low-discrepancy sequences.

I am writing a program that relies on using a low-discrepancy sequence for sampling in 2D. Hammersley, Sobol, blue noise, and the golden set work just fine for the problem in general. My issue is that I need to have m sets of n points, and each of these sets should be low-discrepancy, the union of these sets should also be low discrepancy. My question is whether this is feasible at all, and whether anybody knows of a paper on the subject.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you mentioned, the traditional techniques including Halton, Kronecker, Sobol and hammersely are very good at producing low discrepancy sequences in 2-dimensions. However, it is not so clear how you can extend these to make sets of low discrepancy sequences.

However, I have recently written a detailed blog post ["The unreasonable effectiveness of quasirandom sequences](http://extremelearning.com.au/unreasonable-effectiveness-of-quasirandom-sequences/), which satisfies your requirement.

The solution is an additive recurrence method (modulo 1) which generalizes the 1-Dimensional problem whose solution depends on the Golden Ratio. The solution to the $d$-dimensional problem, depends on a special constant $\phi_d$, where $\phi_d$ is the unique positive root of $ x^{d+1}=x+1$.

For $d=1$,  $ \phi_1 = 1.618033989... $, which is the canonical golden ratio.

And for $d=2$, $ \phi_2 = 1.3247179572... $, which  is often called the plastic constant, and has some beautiful properties. This value was conjectured to most likely be the optimal value for a related two-dimensional problem [Hensley, 2002].

Jacob Rus has posted a beautiful visualization of this 2-dimensional low discrepancy sequence, which can be found [here](https://beta.observablehq.com/@jrus/plastic-sequence).

With this special constant in hand, the calculation of the $n$-th term is now extremely simple and fast to calculate:

$$ R: \mathbf{t}_n = \pmb{\alpha}_0 + n \pmb{\alpha}  \; (\textrm{mod} \; 1),  \quad n=1,2,3,... $$
$$ \textrm{where} \quad \pmb{\alpha} =(\frac{1}{\phi_d}, \frac{1}{\phi_d^2},\frac{1}{\phi_d^3},...\frac{1}{\phi_d^d}), $$

Of course, the reason this is called a recurrence sequence is because the above definition is equivalent to 
$$ R: \mathbf{t}_{n+1} =  \mathbf{t}_{n} +  \pmb{\alpha}  \; (\textrm{mod} \; 1) $$

In nearly all instances, the choice of $\pmb{\alpha}_0 $ does not change the key characteristics, and so for reasons of obvious simplicity, $\pmb{\alpha}_0 =\pmb{0}$ is the usual choice. However, there are some arguments, relating to symmetry, that suggest that $\pmb{\alpha}_0=\pmb{1/2}$  is a better choice.

Specifically for $d=2$, $ \phi_2 = 1.3247179572... $ and so for $\pmb{\alpha}_0= (1/2,1/2) $, 
$$\pmb{\alpha} = (0.754878, 0.56984) $$ and so the first 5 terms of the canonical 2-dimensional sequence are:

1. (0.254878, 0.0698403)
2. (0.00975533, 0.639681)
3. (0.764633, 0.209521)
4. (0.519511, 0.779361)
5. (0.274388, 0.349201)

**One elegant characteristic of this sequence is that not only does each consecutive sequence of $n$ terms exhibit local low discrepancy, but also the entire $mn$ terms exhibits global low discrepancy.**

The following diagram illustrates this characteristic with 4 sets of 100 low discrepancy points. That is,  $(n=100,m=4)$.
[image: multi-scale low discrepancy point set]

The Python code for each set is

```
# Use Newton-Rhapson-Method
def gamma(d):
    x=1.0000
    for i in range(20):
        x = x-(pow(x,d+1)-x-1)/((d+1)*pow(x,d)-1)
    return x
d=2
n=100

g = gamma(d)
alpha = np.zeros(d)                 
for j in range(d):
    alpha[j] = pow(1/g,j+1) %1
z = np.zeros((n, d))    
for i in range(n):
    z = (0.5 + alpha*(i+1)) %1
print(z)
```

Futhermore, this technique works even if the sets have different cardinality. For example, in the figure below there are 150 points: 75 blue, 40 orange, 25 green and 10 red. One can see that the method of multi-set low discrepancy distributions can be achieved quite well for the R-sequence, Halton and (some) Kronecker distributions, but for Sobol and Niederreiter sequence notables color artefacts appear.

[image]

Hope that helps!

Comment: That was very helpful indeed. Thank you very much for the detailed answer and the great link.

Comment: and where did the number 20 come from in the python code, and the block of the Newton-Raphson algorithm?

Comment: The newton raphson codebb be is a quick way to calculate the specials basis constants (generalised version of the golden ratio), which is the root of x^d = x+1. 
The 20 is a somewhat arbitrary number of iterations required to get the newton raphson algorithm to converge within 32 bit floating point precision

Comment: Thanks Martin! You have developed a very interesting algorithm. I am trying to apply it in my work. If I have any additional questions, I will try to ask them.

Answer (score 1):

you want e.g. to take two 2D point sets to form a 4D set? This will usually not work fine, and of course there are algorithms to directly generate a 4-dimensional low-discrepancy set (or 8D or whatever, like Sobol). It is most easy to see from a 1D analogon: Taking two 1D equidistant sets leads to a 2D set looking like a 45-degree stripe, having very bad space filling properties. Maybe it is good enough for you to take two 2D set with some randomization, so that at least e.g. the combination of 2nd and 3rd variable has random properties (but not low discrepancy)??

Comment: I want the union of these sets to be low discrepancy not the product(the union would still be a 2d set).
Formally my problem looks like this:

Comment: Formally my problem looks like this:
I am looking for m low-discrepancy sets Ai (i = 1,...,m) with points in [0,1]^2 and |Ai|=n, such that
C=A1 U A2 U ... U Am, and C is also low-discrepancy. As I have noted before - I am unsure whether this is feasible at all.